# Est-ce que l'expression "sur papier libre" signifie qu'il faut que le document soit manuscrit ?

Tags: correspondance

Je dois joindre une lettre à un dossier destiné au Ministère de la Justice. Il est écrit que cette "requête personnelle sur papier libre adressée au ministre de la justice [...] doit être *datée et signée*". J'ai du mal à comprendre le sens de "sur papier libre" dans ce contexte. Cela signifie-t-il qu'il faut que la requête soit écrite à la main ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

« Sur papier libre » signifie qu'il n'y a pas de formulaire particulier à remplir. Il suffit de prendre une feuille de papier et d'écrire. Peu importe que ce soit écrit à la main ou à la machine, du moment que c'est lisible.

La signature, au minimum, doit être manuscrite. Certaines démarches exigent également une date manuscrite ou une formule spécifique manuscrite, mais cela sera mentionné explicitement. Tout le reste peut être imprimé.

L'antonyme de « sur papier libre » est « sur le formulaire n° *XXX* ».

Certains dictionnaires définissent « papier libre » comme « papier non timbré », mais cette définition est obsolète. Le [papier timbré](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papier_timbr%C3%A9), une feuille de papier pour lequel il faut payer une taxe, a [disparu en 1986](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papier_timbr%C3%A9#Le_cr%C3%A9puscule_des_papiers_timbr%C3%A9s). De nos jours, s'il faut payer, le [timbre fiscal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbre_fiscal_mobile) est à acheter séparément et à coller comme on colle un timbre postal sur une enveloppe (il existe aussi sous forme électronique). La plupart des démarches qui demandent un timbre fiscal exigent un formulaire spécifique, mais il doit bien exister des cas où il faut payer avec un timbre fiscal pour une demande qui se fait sur papier libre.

---

“*Sur papier libre*” means that you can use a plain sheet of paper. Its antonym is “*sur le formulaire n° XXX*” (using form nr. XXX). It doesn't matter whether the text is printed or handwritten as long as it's legible. The signature must be handwritten.

Answer (score 2):

« sur papier libre » signifie sur papier non timbré (timbre fiscal) peu importe que ce soit une lettre manuscrite ou dactylographiée.

Voir [papier libre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/papier_libre)

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Cela signifie donc qu'il n'y a pas à faire authentifier le courrier, c'est bien cela ?

Comment: @avazula: L'authentification n'a rien à voir ici. Il suffit simplement comme indiqué dans la demande de dater et signer.

Comment: Je parlais de la [signification](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papier_timbr%C3%A9) de "papier timbré" ; c'est ce que j'en ai compris en la lisant mais je n'en suis pas sûre.

Comment: @avazula: Un papier timbré est une (ou plusieurs) feuille sur laquelle on colle un timbre fiscal.

Comment: D'accord. Merci pour vos précisions.

Comment: Non, cette définition est obsolète. « Sur papier libre » signifie qu'il n'y a pas de formulaire particulier à remplir, c'est (de nos jours) indépendant de s'il faut payer ou non.